# How to pass props of Redirect in enzyme test case

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

I have written a test case for snapshot testing for a mount of component (PasswordReset). In my code, I am passing a prop in Redirect, something like this -

`<Redirect to={{pathname: '/forgotPassword', state: this.state.email}} />`

I want to pass the same props of Redirect tag in a test case. The problem is PasswordReset component uses this prop to initialize a value in state in constructor. So, my test case fails saying -

```
Cannot read property 'state' of undefined
```

I have searched and found some answers about how to write test cases for Routes but I haven't got any solution for this problem. My test case is this -

```
it ("Check if rendering properly", () => {
    const wrapper = mount (
        <MemoryRouter initialEntries={['/forgotPassword']}>
            <PasswordReset />
        </MemoryRouter>
    );

    expect(wrapper.find(PasswordReset)).toMatchSnapshot();
});
```

Sorry, I am new to testing in React. I want to know how to pass this prop.